# comparing data regularity

Tags: python, variance, model, curve-fitting

I have data about ratings from 5 sessions, it appears that initially ratings are random, and with experience, they become more 'defined', settling into a pattern (see graph below). How can I test this intuition?

[image]

Comment: Please describe your experiment and explain what "ratings," "sessions,"  and "stimuli #" are.  Bear in mind that such *post hoc* tests are difficult to justify, which makes it especially important to present the details of your situation clearly and fully.

Comment: Subjects rated 50 images on a 1-10 scale on 5 separate back to back blocks, each block the images were randomized. I realize my wording makes it seem like a post hoc, but there is very good reason to expect changes in underlying preference after repeated ratings. Note, the images are all related (code generated with the same underlying pixel colors but different degrees of symmetry and orderliness).